# Query on TFP Probabilistic Model

Tags: tensorflow-probability

In the TFP [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Probabilistic_Layers_Regression), the model output is Normal distribution. I noted that the output can be replaced by an IndependentNormal layer. In my model, the y_true is binary class. Therefore, I used an IndependentBernoulli layer instead of IndependentNormal layer.

After building the model, I found that it has two output parameters. It doesn't make sense to me since Bernoulli distribution has one parameter only. Do you know what went wrong?

```
# Define the prior weight distribution as Normal of mean=0 and stddev=1.
# Note that, in this example, the we prior distribution is not trainable,
# as we fix its parameters.
def prior(kernel_size, bias_size, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    prior_model = Sequential([
            tfpl.DistributionLambda(
                lambda t: tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=tf.zeros(n), scale_diag=tf.ones(n))
            )
        ])
    return prior_model

# Define variational posterior weight distribution as multivariate Gaussian.
# Note that the learnable parameters for this distribution are the means,
# variances, and covariances.
def posterior(kernel_size, bias_size, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    posterior_model = Sequential([
            tfpl.VariableLayer(tfpl.MultivariateNormalTriL.params_size(n), dtype=dtype),
            tfpl.MultivariateNormalTriL(n)
        ])
    return posterior_model

# Create a probabilistic DL model
model = Sequential([
       tfpl.DenseVariational(units=16,
                             input_shape=(6,),
                             make_prior_fn=prior,
                             make_posterior_fn=posterior,
                             kl_weight=1/X_train.shape[0],
                             activation='relu'),
       tfpl.DenseVariational(units=16,
                             make_prior_fn=prior,
                             make_posterior_fn=posterior,
                             kl_weight=1/X_train.shape[0],
                             activation='sigmoid'),
       tfpl.DenseVariational(units=tfpl.IndependentBernoulli.params_size(1),
                             make_prior_fn=prior,
                             make_posterior_fn=posterior,
                             kl_weight=1/X_train.shape[0]),
       tfpl.IndependentBernoulli(1, convert_to_tensor_fn=tfd.Bernoulli.logits)
])             
model.summary()
```

[screenshot of the results executed the codes on Google Colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvp6w.png)

Answer (score 0):

I agree the summary display is confusing but I think this is an artifact of the way tfp layers are implemented to interact with keras. During normal operation, there will only be one return value from a `DistributionLambda` layer. But in some contexts (that I don't fully grok) `DistributionLambda`.call may return both a distribution and a side-result. I think the summary plumbing triggers this for some reason, so it looks like there are 2 outputs, but there will practically only be one. Try calling your model object on X_train, and you'll see you get a single distribution out (its  type is actually something called `TensorCoercible`, which is a wrapper around a distribution that lets you pass it into tf ops that call tf.convert_to_tensor -- the resulting value for that op will be the result of calling your convert_to_tensor_fn on the enclosed distribution).

In summary, your distribution layer is fine but the summary is confusing. It could probably be fixed; I'm not keras-knowledgeable enough to opine on how hard it would be.

Side note: you can omit the event_shape=1 parameter -- the default value is (), or "scalar", which will behave the same.

HTH!

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for your reply. Indeed, it is very helpful. I had the same impression. With your input, I know the results of the model is correct.